# R tibble/flextable manipulation

Tags: r

In Rstudio, given data structured in the following manner:

```
df<-data.frame(
    "Category"=c("Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2")
    "Item"=c("Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4")
```

How can I create a horizontal flextable table in which the categories form columns with the relevant items stacked underneath along with their frequencies? I can create an almost correct data frame using the following, but receive a `duplicated col_keys` error when I attempt to create a flextable from it :

```
df<-data.frame(table(df))
df1<-data.frame(t(df[-1]))
colnames(df1)<-df[,1]
```

For clarity sake, I would like the data to look like the following:
[image]